# ssi nginx непонятный пробел перед вставкой

Tags: nginx, ssi

Ситуация такая: apache выдает страницу nginx который вставляет в нее по ssi некоторые блоки. Проблема в том что перед вставленным блоком ставится непонятный пробел которого в самом вставляемом блоке нету. Этот пробел портит верстку, но как его убрать я понять не могу. Если кто-то встречался подскажите как убрать?

Comment: плачу 100 рублей на телефон если ктото реально поможет решить проблему! за сегодня

Comment: @greshnik, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

где код, где это посмотреть. Экстрасенсы после летнего отпуска ушли в зимнюю спячку, и будить их мы не можем, они порчу наводят на всех тогда.

Comment: У вас 100% где-то [BOM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) завёлся :-) Он многим вёрстку портит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказывается не стоит закрывать пхп теги если этого не требуется =) и никаких bom-ов не будет